# Itroduction to Runge theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have the following problem. Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $K$ be a compact subset of $\Omega$. Let $O$ be a relatively compact component of $\Omega \setminus K$. Then the boundary $\partial O$ is the subset of $K$? How to prove this?

I was thinking about a contradiction with the copmactness of the $\text{cl}O$.

Comment: Every boundary point of $O$ must lie either in $K$ or in $\Omega\setminus K$. If there were a point $p \in \partial O \cap (\Omega\setminus K)$, could $O$ be a component of $\Omega\setminus K$?

Comment: So, suppose $p \in \partial O\, \cap (\Omega \setminus K)$. Since $\Omega$ is open and $K$ is compact, $\Omega \setminus K$ is open. Denote $R=\text{dist}(p, \Omega \setminus K)$. Choose $0<r<R$. Then $B(p,r)\in \Omega \setminus K$ which I guess leads to a contradiction with the $O$ being a component of $\Omega \setminus K$.

Comment: What can you say about $O \cup B(p,r)$?

Comment: Since $O$ is the component of $\Omega \setminus K$ and the ball $B(p,r)\subset \Omega \setminus K$, then $O\cup B(p,r)=O$ ?

Comment: Yes, but there's an argument missing. Why do you conclude $O\cup B(p,r) = O$?

Comment: Maybe it is time to use the information that $O$ is relatively compact or make a use of $O$ being a component of $\Omega \setminus K$? My first thought is, that $O$ is the maximal in the sens of inclusion connected subset of $\Omega \setminus K$, but I don't think that implies $O\cup B(p,r)=O$. So relative compactness is about to be used.

Comment: We used the relative compactness to deduce that no boundary point of $O$ lies outside $\Omega$. So now we should use that $O$ is a component.

Comment: You meant $x\in \partial O\subset \text{cl}O\subset \Omega$.

Comment: Yes. Where the boundary and closure are to be understood with respect to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Well, I don't  know. I recall a theorem that says that a component is closed.

Comment: That's not relevant here. What we need is that a component is a _maximal_ connected subset. So we can deduce $O \cup B(p,r) = O$ if we show that the union is connected.

Comment: To do so we need to have $O\cap B(p,r)\neq \emptyset$. Else, the union of two disjoint sets is not connected.

Comment: And why is the intersection nonempty here?

Comment: Because $p\in \partial O$.

Comment: Okay. Can you assemble everything into a proof now?

Comment: So far I obatined $O\cap B(p,r)=O$ means that $p\in  O$ and in the same time $p\in \partial O$. I need a cotradiction now.

Comment: Well, $O$ is an open set. And open sets don't intersect their boundary.

Comment: I was thinking about it but once again I recall the thorem that concerns the closedness of the the component.

Comment: Yes, but the question is "closed in which space"? In this case, it's closed in $\Omega \setminus K$. Since that's an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{C}$ is locally connected, components of $\Omega\setminus K$ are also open (first in $\Omega \setminus K$, then, since that is open in $\mathbb{C}$, they are also open in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: I agree. Thank you so much for your help and commitment. Now everything is clear.